# Adding multiple buttons on node submit form - every button submits the form

Tags: 7, forms

I am adding several buttons to a node form.  The result is something that looks like [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/rLwCQRcM).  The pastebin is a somewhat truncated version, here is the real short one:

```
$form = [
  '#submit' => [],
  '#actions' => [
   'submit' => [
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#submit' => ['node_form_submit']
   ],
   'skip_done' => [
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#submit' => ['skip_done_handler']
   ],
];
```

I *thought* that if `$form['#submit']` was empty then the only submit handlers that would be called are the ones on the respective buttons.  I'm either completely wrong in my understanding or I've misconfigured something.

Should this work they way I'm expecting it to?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave `$form['#submit']` unset or empty then [drupal_prepare_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_prepare_form/7.x) will try to replace it with a submit handler provided by the base form:

```
if (!isset($form['#submit'])) {

// Ensure that modules can rely on #submit being set.
$form['#submit'] = array(

);

// Check for a handler specific to $form_id.
if (function_exists($form_id . '_submit')) {
  $form['#submit'][] = $form_id . '_submit';
}
elseif (isset($form_state['build_info']['base_form_id']) && function_exists($form_state['build_info']['base_form_id'] . '_submit')) {
  $form['#submit'][] = $form_state['build_info']['base_form_id'] . '_submit';
}
```

If you're submitting a node form then `$form_state['build_info']['base_form_id'] . '_submit'` will be equal to `node_form_submit`, which is why it's being called.

In order to prevent `node_form_submit` from being called, you'll need to provide a `$form['#submit']` handler, or define `FORMID_form_submit`, which takes the form `NODETYPE_node_form_submit` for nodes.